# cakephp condition OR with order sorting not working

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Code is not working condition is working but order sorting is not working

Please help me what is the issue

```
$this->Offer->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                array('Offer.branch_id' => 1),
                array('Offer.branch_id' => $branch['Branch']['id'])
            )
        )
    ),
    array('order' => array('Offer.order_no' => 'DESC'))
);
```

Comment: With the now properly formatted code, you should easily [spot your mistake](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find). Using proper formatting helps a lot to avoid such issues.

Comment: Whats the issue here? I think code is right

Comment: @ndm for my own Stack Overflow learning experience: is it not just better to answer the question? I know the mistake might be obvious to most experienced CakePHP users, but maybe not to the OP.

Comment: @InigoFlores The problem here is merely more than a typo, it could easily be resolved by just formatting the code example properly, and checking it back against the docs. It's unlikely that such a question will help future readers, and therefore I'd tend to close it instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic point 2.

Comment: @ndm I see what you mean. I didn't notice the PHP syntax error, and thought it was just an unsupported syntax for `find()`. I agree, it provides little value for future readers... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :->

```
$this->Offer->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                array('Offer.branch_id' => 1),
                array('Offer.branch_id' => $branch['Branch']['id'])
            )
        ),
        'order' => array('Offer.order_no' => 'DESC')
    )
);
```

Comment: You amost got it right. However, because you have removed the `array()` wrap within the `OR` conditions, `Offer.branch_id` will overwrite itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Offer->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            'Offer.branch_id' => 1,
            'Offer.branch_id' => $branch['Branch']['id']
        )
    ),
    'order' => array('Offer.order_no DESC')
));
```

1. In OR => array, there's no array again,
2. Place the order after conditions, and make the format like 'order' => array('Offer.order_no DESC')
   ,

DESC = descending, is sort order_no from last
ASC = ascending, sort from first

Comment: Please explain your answer so people can learn from it. SO is not a code-writing service and your answers shouldn't imply that either

Comment: I'm sorry, i wanna to explain my answer but my format code error, now i has been edited my answer, i hope my answer can be helpful..

Comment: Your update looks fine; but do you realize you are posting a duplicate answer? It's exactly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/34556016/3749523

Comment: I try my code and working, but else answer i never try, i dont know wheter in  array "OR" have any array is same T_T